# Python: Get the name of an imported function

Tags: python, function

Is it possible to get the name of an imported function if I import it using an alias?

For example: Importing getcwd as pwd:

```
>>> from os import getcwd as pwd
```

and asking for the name of "pwd" yields:

```
>>> pwd.__name__
'getcwd'
```

I would like to find a way to see the value 'pwd'. Is that somehow possible?

Comment: That would be the function's alias, not its name

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: `pwd.__name__` is a function attribute that could be anything, but the `def` statement sets to the same string it uses to create the variable name. Do you have a particular use case for getting the variable name as Python data?

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that this is called an alias, still learning. Admittedly, this is more of a hypothetical example, I was wondering if this was possible at all.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a better way but you could just access its key from the `locals` listing, not sure why you'd want to though.

```
>>> next(k for k, v in locals().items() if v == pwd)
'pwd'
```

As noted in the comments, this will only work if only one key in the dictionary is referencing the given function.

Comment: This assumes that only one name in the local scope refers to the function, or that you want the (arbitrarily chosen) first name.

Comment: @chepner - Admittedly, I didn't put much effort into this.

Comment: @chepner Wouldn't it (since Python 3.7) give you the *first* name it was imported as, rather than an arbitrarily chosen one?

Comment: @StefanPochmann Probably, though it depends on how `locals` actually creates the `dict` it returns. I wouldn't rely on it.